# SUM a random number of values using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the length of a line by using "Math.Sqrt" function and it's X,Y coordinates. So this coordinates are read from a text file and coordinates for more than one line can appear, which means that the function will calculate the length of every line. Here is how the code looks:

Dim Perimeter As List(Of Line) = LineParsing(fp)

```
    For Each Line As Line In Perimeter

        Dim x1 As Single = Line.Start.X
        Dim y1 As Single = Line.Start.Y
        Dim x2 As Single = Line.End.X
        Dim y2 As Single = Line.End.Y
        Dim Pq As Double

        Pq = (Math.Sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)))

        'Using textbox to see the output.
        TextBox4.AppendText("Line Length: " & Pq & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Now the result that I am trying to achieve is to sum these line's lengths which will give me the perimeter of a form.

Any ideas how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable before your for loop that holds the sum. Add the result of your calculation to the sum variable in the loop and output or use the result after the loop.

```
Dim sumOfLines As Double = 0

For Each Line As Line In Perimeter
    ' ...

    Pq = (Math.Sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)))
    sumOfLines += Pq ' add line length to sum

   ' ...
Next

' do something with sumOfLines here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! Works just fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate the length calculation into your `Line` structure/class. That way you won't have to re type the calculation each time you want to use it. and after each calculation just add it to a variable that holds the total.

The added benefit is that if you want to change the calculation, you'll only have to change it in one place.

```
Structure Line
    Friend Start As Point
    Friend [End] As Point
    Friend ReadOnly Property Length As Double
        Get
            Dim x1 As Single = Start.X
            Dim y1 As Single = Start.Y
            Dim x2 As Single = [End].X
            Dim y2 As Single = [End].Y
            Return Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure
```

**Example Code**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim perimiter As New List(Of Line)
    perimiter.Add(New Line With {.Start = New Point(0, 0), .End = New Point(3, 4)})
    perimiter.Add(New Line With {.Start = New Point(3, 4), .End = New Point(8, 2)})
    perimiter.Add(New Line With {.Start = New Point(8, 2), .End = New Point(6, 1)})
    perimiter.Add(New Line With {.Start = New Point(6, 1), .End = New Point(0, 0)})
    Dim totalLength As Double = 0
    For Each line As Line In perimiter
        TextBox4.AppendText("Line Length: " & line.Length & Environment.NewLine)
        totalLength += line.Length
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David I do have a similar structure since the result I want to achieve is a bit different but i haven't thought about including the Math.Sqrt function into the structure so thanks! I guess when it's all set and done I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hehe. At the end of the day, the length is a property of the line :)